# Ordinal equation

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

Here's a question from Kuratowski's "Set theory" (Chapter 7).

Given the ordinal equation $\omega^a=b+c$ $(c>0)$. How to prove that $c=\omega^a$?

Comment: By $w$ do you mean $\omega$? Hint: what happens if you just apply the recursive definition of ordinal exponentiation?

Comment: @Mees yes, I've tried but failed